# Ubuntu 16.04 - Python 3 - Pyperclip in terminal and via systemd

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, service, system, pyperclip

Currently i am working on a little application which deals with the pyperclip module.

First of all, my setup:

ubuntu 16.04 | python3 | pyperclip 1.6.0 (newest! 2017-11-08)

**Situation 1:**

When i run my python script directly:

```
python3 app.py
```

it all works fine!

**Situation 2:**

When i first build my app via pyinstaller and after run the app:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name app app.py

./app
```

it all works fine!

**Situation 3:**

When i build my app and run it via systemd:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/absolute/path/to/executable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i start the new service and check logs via journalctl, i get:

pyperclip.PyperclipException
   pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system

**Soooo..** i know there are some issues for linux user and i exactly followed instruction and installed all missing modules:

```
sudo apt-get install xclip xsel -y
```

Issue still remaining...

Can anybody explain why i can run my executable directly in terminal but not via systemd?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but are `xclip` and `xsel` installed in /usr/bin/? or /usr/local/bin/? I know my scheduled tasks had to be explicitly stated /usr/local/bin/python3 so I'd assume system fired tasks are always looking for executables in /usr/bin.

Comment: they are all in /usr/bin why? how should i proceed?

Comment: Sorry then I'm not sure.  I'm not familiar enough with ubuntu/linux.

Comment: am i really alone with this issue? why cant i get my service starting properly...

Comment: Have you tried installing the rest of the modules listed here and give it another try? https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error

Comment: In any case, if all else fails, google is your best friend: https://www.google.ca/search?q=pyperclip+could+not+find+a+copy%2Fpaste+mechanism+for+your+system&oq=pyperclip+could+not+find+a+copy%2Fpaste+mechanism+for+your+system&aqs=chrome..69i57.823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: man... i did all of this. the PROBLEM still is: when i run the executable directly, it works. When i run it via systemd service file, it fails. any suggestions?

Comment: maybe this answer applies can solve your problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73145297/544947